# try catch on static function asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, highcharts, alert

i try show error message

i have a link button in grid view ..i call highcharts when i click on this link button and also this static function.. through this static function i get data and then call this function through javascript so when i click on this button chart is display but when there is no chart it shows error in code so for this i want to show alert box when there is no chart..

```
public static function(int ID)
try
{
}
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 Response.Write("<script>alert('" + Server.HtmlEncode(ex.ToString()) + "')</script>");
 }
```

i try above but this shows error message

> **Error   3** An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.Server.get'
>    **Error    2** An object
>   reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property
>   'System.Web.UI.Page.Response.get'

`lbViewChart` is link button ... 
jquery

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var strArray = "[['sfdsdfLi', 9],['Kiwsdfi', 3],['Mixesdfd nuts', 1],['Oranges', 6],['Grapes (bunch)', 1]]";
     $(function () {
    $('[ID*=lbViewChart]').on('click', function () {
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        var Id = row.find('td')[0].firstChild.data;
        var obj = {};
        obj.ID = Id;
        GetData(obj);
        return false;
    });
});
    function GetData(obj) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetVoiliations",
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {

                alert(result.d);
                alert('u');
                //start
                strArray = result.d;
                var myarray = eval(strArray);


                $('#container').highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        type: 'pie',
                        options3d: {
                            enabled: true,
                            alpha: 45
                        }
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Contents of Highsoft\'s weekly fruit delivery'
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: '3D donut in Highcharts'
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        pie: {
                            innerSize: 100,
                            depth: 45
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Delivered amount',
                        data: myarray
                    }]
                });

                //end
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error);
            }

        });
        }

    //  });

        </script>
```

any solution?

Comment: MessageBox.Show is for windows form.

Comment: yes  i know but how i show alert box

Comment: @Dr.Stitch i update question please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access `Server` directly in a static method instead for that use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server` So the code will be like:

```
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>alert('" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(ex.ToString()) + "')</script>");
```

Or include `using System.Web;` to the using section and then use `HttpContext.Current.Server`

**Updates: -**

The [`HttpContext.Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current(v=vs.110).aspx) is a static property so you can access it Directly inside a static method. and hence you can access `.Server` and .Response` from this as like the following:

```
 System.Web.HttpContext currentContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
 currentContext.Response.Write("<script>alert('" + currentContext.Server.HtmlEncode(ex.ToString()) + "')</script>");
```

Comment: this shows error  "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.Response.get'"

Comment: on this word "Response"

Comment: @SUPER_USER : use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write`

Comment: i use this .. using System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write; and now this shows error   Error 2 The type name 'Current' does not exist in the type 'System.Web.HttpContext'

Comment: @SUPER_USER : The `HttpContext.Current` is a static property, i have some updates in the answer